# Where can I find developer output from Rails application deployed to Torquebox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I have a JRuby on Rails application, which is usually deployed as war to Tomcat. In development mode we use either WEBrick or trinidad (usually first). Now we are considering using Toquebox.

I was able to deploy app using Torquebox, but I wonder where can I find development logs (things like request/response details, executed SQL queries etc). I got used to that stuff. JBoss'es console, boot.log and server.log don't contain those - only torquebox specific logging.

Thanks

Comment: Also, you may need to set the `logger.level` to `DEBUG` in logging.properties if you want to see debug messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are currently in your applications directory, use

```
$ less log/development.log
```

For every enviorement: env

```
$ less log/<env>.log
```

For following it (as it appends) use:

```
$ tail -f log/<env>.log
```